# Dialog with choosing icon

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm sorry, I'm new to android developing.

I need to make a dialog with choosing an icon for each task (Icons load from a db. Maximum 4 icons in a row).

So the problem is how to organize this dialog UI. I had an idea to use 4 vertical RecyclerViews in DialogFragment. But it sounds like a real bad solution. Here is the screenshot example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use GridLayout

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved me. This is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: You are welcome, here a link with complete sample https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example